# Android geocoder Error which is not handled by try catch

Tags: android, geolocation

I am making one application which is displays long lat off inserted address.

It works fine but the problem is only that, When I insert Wrong address name like "abc xyz" in textbox than it stop and displays error on imulator that "Unfortunately, Location has stopped."

I can not understand this, because as i know try and catch can handle any exceptions. Is it true????

There is only one text box and editbox in my sample project this is code of button click.
here is a code ...

```
  try{
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                //List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
                add=et.getText().toString();
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(add, 1);


                if(addresses != null) {
                    Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                    StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("\n");
                    for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        strReturnedAddress.append("Latitude="+addresses.get(0).getLatitude()).append("\n");
                        strReturnedAddress.append("Longitude="+addresses.get(0).getLongitude()).append("\n");
                        strReturnedAddress.append("Country="+addresses.get(0).getCountryName()).append("\n");
                        strReturnedAddress.append("State="+addresses.get(0).getAdminArea()).append("\n");

                    }
                    myAddress.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
                }
                else{
                    myAddress.setText("No Address returned!");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                myAddress.setText("Canont get Address!");
            }
            /*Intent intent=new Intent(Main.this, Horoscope.class);
            intent.putExtra("extra", myAddress.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);*/
        }
    });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        myAddress.setText("Canont get Address!");
    }
```

Comment: try to catch `NullPointerException` and `IOException` bez  geocoder Throws these exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try{ 
                    //List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
            add=et.getText().toString();
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(add, 1);


            if(addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("\n");
                for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append("Latitude="+addresses.get(0).getLatitude()).append("\n");
                    strReturnedAddress.append("Longitude="+addresses.get(0).getLongitude()).append("\n");
                    strReturnedAddress.append("Country="+addresses.get(0).getCountryName()).append("\n");
                    strReturnedAddress.append("State="+addresses.get(0).getAdminArea()).append("\n");

                }
                myAddress.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
            }
            else{
                myAddress.setText("No Address returned!");
            }

           }} catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            myAddress.setText("Canont get Address!");
        }
        /*Intent intent=new Intent(Main.this, Horoscope.class);
        intent.putExtra("extra", myAddress.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);*/
    }
});
}

           catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UR MESSAGE" ,      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, YourActivity.class));
                   finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
try
{
 Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"UR MESSAGE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 startActivity(new Intent(this, YourActivity.class));
 finish();
 }
```

I hope you ll get it..